# Use Multiple IP addresses in the same NIC to Split Internet Requests

Tags: command-line, networking, server, python

How I can use multiple IP addresses that I've added to my NIC to send different requests to different servers?
For example, my IP address is:

```
10.0.0.4
```

I've added two more IP addresses to my NIC:

```
10.0.0.5
10.0.0.6
```

My question is, how can I split the requests? For example, use `10.0.0.5` to browse the internet only, and use `10.0.0.6` to download an application from terminal. (Using command-line or a python script)

Answer (score 3):

The software which sends request can probably bind to a specified address ,look at the parameters or config file

If you are using [`socket.create_connection()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.create_connection) , the last parameter is `source_address`

https://serverfault.com/questions/496731/how-to-set-which-ip-to-use-for-a-http-request

```
wget --bind-address=10.0.0.6
```

For browsing internet, the source ip is determined by routing parameter `preferred source` , but that is a networking question i could not find any answers on how to change.

Answer (score 0):

for browser, setup [squid](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/squid.html) proxy server and enter proxy ip(10.0.0.5) with port number into browser.

```
sudo apt-get install squid3

http_access allow test_network

acl test_network src 10.0.0.5

sudo service squid3 restart
```